# Mouse event position on a canvas rescaled by a CSS rule

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, mouseevent

When a HTML canvas is in "standard" 1:1 scale (neither enlarged nor shrinked by a CSS rule), it is simple to get the mouse position in the canvas coordinates:

```
c2.onpointermove = (e) => {
    var mousemove_coords = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };
```

Here is an example where the canvas' size gets modified by `flex` + `max-width` CSS rules. The cursor should change only on top of the green square, which is not the case here, the cursor changes on bottom right of the square.

**How to get the coordinates of a mouse event over a canvas when it is resized by a CSS rule?**

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"), ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"), ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
var w = 2000, h = 1000;
var x0 = 50, y0 = 75, x1 = 100, y1 = 200;
ctx1.canvas.width = w;
ctx1.canvas.height = h; 
ctx1.rect(0, 0, w, h);
ctx1.fill();
ctx2.canvas.width = w;
ctx2.canvas.height = h; 
ctx2.rect(x0, y0, x1, y1);
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.fill();
c2.onpointermove = (e) => {
    var mousemove_coords = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };
    var hovered =
        mousemove_coords.x >= x0 &&
        mousemove_coords.x <= x1 &&
        mousemove_coords.y >= y0 &&
        mousemove_coords.y <= y1;
    c2.style.cursor = hovered ? "move" : "crosshair";
};
```

```css
body, .container { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-color: yellow; }
.left-column { margin: 1rem; flex: 1; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
.canvas-wrapper { position: relative; }
#canvas1 { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
#canvas2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.right-column { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-column column">
        <div class="canvas-wrapper">
            <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column column">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: in my real code, I'm drawing on the canvas from frames received by HTTP requests with:

```
update_frame_task = setInterval(() => {
        fetch("get_frame")
            .then((r) => r.arrayBuffer())
            .then((arr) => {
                if (size === null) {
                    size = { w: 2000, h: 1000 };
                    ctx.canvas.width = size.w;
                    ctx.canvas.height = size.h;
                    ctx2.canvas.width = size.w;
                    ctx2.canvas.height = size.h;
                }
                var byteArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(arr);
                var imgData = new ImageData(byteArray, size.w, size.h);
                ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
            });
    }, 200);
```

Comment: You shouldn't resize a canvas with CSS in the first place, it makes the image blurry.

Comment: @Teemu In some cases I have no choice, because my canvas container can receive stream from various cameras, some of them of width 2000, some of them of width 600. I need to limit with a `max-width`, thus automatically resizing the canvas. Do you see another option, if you have a camera display in an interface, and you want this display to have a maximum width in the interface?

Comment: If I've understood your comment correctly, I'd recalculate `width` and `height` accordingly instead of resizing the canvas with CSS.

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean by recalculating the `width` and `height`? Can you elaborate on this? Thanks a lot! In my example, I'm receiving a stream of 2000 x 1000 pixels frames, to be displayed on the canvas. But I don't have a width of 2000 px available in my interface, so this should fit in, say, a width of 800 px. Thus the rescaling. How would you do this?

Comment: Would it be possible to scale the image to draw rather than the canvas? Maybe you should ask a new question about this approach, with a small use-case.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. I will think about this option (rescaling / resampling the image before sending it to the canvas). But let's say we keep the option "big 2000 x 1000 px frame stream, to be displayed on a canvas which is resized to a real width of 800 px by CSS rule", how would you get the right mouse event position on canvas (see my snippet example)?

Comment: What exactly makes the canvas CSS dimensions to change? Just drawing content to it doesn't resize the canvas. Anyway, when the dimension change takes place, you've to calculate the scale compared to the original, then simply multiply the coordinates with the scale. But, when you're calculating the scale, you could simply change `width` and `height` of the canvas instead, and keep the CSS dimensions untouched.

Comment: @Teemu I do change the `width` with `ctx1.canvas.width = 2000;` if the stream of frames is of size 2000 px x 1000 px. If I'm correct, this is different from the style width / CSS width, ie. `document.getElementById("canvas1").style.width`. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, changing width/height of the canvas adds/reduces the amount of the pixels in the canvas, changing CSS dimensions only stretches the existing pixels (that makes the image to look awafull, if the scaling factor is large/small enough). Depending on the exact method which you use to draw the image, it's possible to scale the image with the same command, ex. with [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). That way the physical dimensions would be kept, but the image is scaled instead, with a proper algorithm resulting sharper image.

Comment: @Teemu Oh do you mean `drawImage` can directly do the scaling from input size (2000 x 1000) to another size (800 x ...)? Then I have to think about it. Please copy/paste the concatenation of all your comments as an answer, I'll upvote, they are very helpful :) and they will be helpful to other readers for future reference! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, `drawImage` can do that. If you'd added something really using `drawImage` to the question, then I'll compose an answer, otherwise it won't be an answer to your actual question (scaling mouse coordinates).

Comment: @Teemu I edited the question at the end to include the code that gets the data from HTTP requests and then draws it to canvas. I did use `putImageData` to draw data from an array buffer but feel free to post an answer with `drawImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the mouse co-ordinates to the CSS resize using `getComputedStyle`.

Also, canvas `rect` uses width and height.

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"), ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"), ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
var w = 2000, h = 1000;
var x0 = 50, y0 = 75, x1 = 100, y1 = 200;
ctx1.canvas.width = w;
ctx1.canvas.height = h; 
ctx1.rect(0, 0, w, h);
ctx1.fill();
ctx2.canvas.width = w;
ctx2.canvas.height = h; 
ctx2.rect(x0, y0, x1, y1);
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.fill();
ratio=w/parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(c2).width);
c2.onpointermove = (e) => {

    var mousemove_coords = { x: e.offsetX*ratio, y: e.offsetY*ratio };

    k.innerHTML=mousemove_coords.x+'<br>'+mousemove_coords.y; // scaled coords

    var hovered =
        mousemove_coords.x >= x0 &&
        mousemove_coords.x <= x0+x1 &&
        mousemove_coords.y >= y0 &&
        mousemove_coords.y <= y0+y1;
    c2.style.cursor = hovered ? "move" : "crosshair";
};
```

```css
body, .container { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-color: yellow; }
.left-column { margin: 1rem; flex: 1; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
.canvas-wrapper { position: relative; }
#canvas1 { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
#canvas2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.right-column { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-column column">
        <div class="canvas-wrapper">
            <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='k' class="right-column column">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't resize the CSS size of the canvas, the image in it only gets blurry. Instead, scale the image. As `putImageData` doesn't support scaling, use [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to draw the image into the canvas, it has the ability to scale the image. Since ImageData object can't be passed to `drawImage`, you've to convert it to ImageBitmap using [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap). With these changes your `fetch` should look something like this:

```
fetch("get_frame")
  .then((r) => r.arrayBuffer())
  .then(async (arr) => {
    if (size === null) {
      size = {
        w: 2000,
        h: 1000
      };
     }
    var byteArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(arr);
    var imgData = new ImageData(byteArray, size.w, size.h);
    var image = await createImageBitmap(imageData);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 800, 400);
  });
```

This might not fix all the issues, as you've already might have changed the size of the canvas with CSS. To fix that you could remove all the CSS of the canvas, and apply JMP's answer, and set the dimensions with `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas when the layout of the page is created/changes. Responsive canvases are a bit tricky to design.